# Coding a program to display first 3 consonants of users name and last 3 letters of user's surname and every second digit of ID

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am trying to code a program to display first 3 consonants of users name and last 3 letters of user's surname and every second digit of ID and to add a star in the 7th position. I get the ID part correct but not the name and surname part.

```
procedure TForm1.N31Click(Sender: TObject);


var
 Name,Surname,ID,newname,newsurname,newID,newstring:string;
 i,j,k:integer;
begin
newname:='';
newsurname:='';
newid := '';
name := UPPERCASE(inputbox('Name','First name',''));
Surname := inputbox('Surname','Last name','');
ID := Inputbox('ID','ID boy','');
for i := length(name) downto 1 do
begin
if name[i] in ['A','E','I','O','U'] then
 delete(name,i,1);
 newname := newname + name[i];
 newname := copy(newname,1,3);
 end;

 begin
j := length(surname);
 newsurname := copy(surname,j-2,3);
  end;
 for k := 1 to length(id) do
   newid := newid + id[2*k];

 newstring := (newname+newsurname+newID);
 insert('*',newstring,7);

 redoutput.Lines.Add(newstring) ;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No I didn't mean to write it like that, it looks more complicated your way.

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? Have you bothered to use the debugger yet? What input have you tried, and what output did you get? What output did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Well @SirRufo changed my code to something else so I can't refer precisely. I am having trouble with the name part, I always get letters with vowels.

Comment: @SirRufo please change it back to how it was I don't like this one.

Comment: Instead of writing your own code for replacing vowels, consider using StrUtils.StringReplace().

Answer (score 3):

I'd move all of your parsing code to a function that you can just pass the first name, surname, and ID and get a returned generated value. Here's a test app that does just that - you can then use whatever way you want to get the values to pass into it.

```
program Project1;

uses
  SysUtils;

function GetID(const sName, sSurname, sID: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
const
  // You can remove the lower case letters if you want to always
  // convert sName to upper case first.
  VowelChars = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(sName) do
  begin
    // Earlier versions of Delphi: if not (sName[i] in VowelChars) then
    if not CharInSet(Name[i], VowelChars) then 
      Result := Result + sName[i];
    if Length(Result) = 3 then
      Break;
  end;

  // Last 3 characters of Surname
  Result := Result + Copy(sSurName, Length(sSurName) - 2, 3);

  // Every even digit of ID
  for i := 1 to Length(sID) do
    if not Odd(i) then
      Result := Result + sID[i];
  // Star in 7th position
  if Length(Result) > 7 then
    Result[7] := '*';
end;

begin
  WriteLn(GetID('James', 'Johnson', '123456ABCD'));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rewrite the main part of the code as follows

```
i:= 0;
j:= 0;
newname:= '';
while i < length (name)
 begin
  inc (i);
  if not (name[i] in vowels) then
   begin
    inc (i);
    newname:= newname + name[i];
    if j = 3 then i:= length (name);
   end;
 end;

i:= length (surname);
if i > 3
 then newsurname:= copy (surname, i - 3, 3) 
 else newsurname:= surname;

newid:= '';
for k := 1 to length (id) do newid := newid + id[2*k];
result:= newname + newsurname + newID);
insert ('*', result, 7);
```

Comment: Your code is broken. 2nd `inc(i)` should be `inc(j)`. Then `if j = 3 then break;` or even better no `j` at all, and `if length(newname)=3 then break;`, which is easier to understand. Then your last `for k := 1 to length (id) do newid := newid + id[2*k];` is just broken and will overflow the buffer... so should be `for k := 1 to length(id) div 2 do ....`